# What is the positive charge in a capacitor made of?

Tags: electricity, electrons, capacitance

A [capacitor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Capacitor) is a pair of conductors separated by an insulator.
When it gets charged we have negative charges in one of the plates and positive charges in the other.

Negative charges are electrons but what are those positive charges in the other plate?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As almost always, the positive charge in an electric circuit component comes from the positively charged atoms of the conducting metal. The electrons move *away* from the plate that is to be positively charged (towards the positive pole of the voltage source with which the capacitor is being charged), and hence there is a net positive charge on the plate, since the ionized atoms' charge is no longer counterweighed by the electrons' charge.

Comment: never mind, I do understand what you mean now. thanks

Answer (score 0):

As per your question, the positive and negative charges exist ideally and all the charges are followed by "electron theory of electrification" which states, that the movement of electrons from high to low or low to high is decided by the type of charge, either positive or negative because by default the protons are positively charged and cannot move!!! So, everything depends on electrons (which are loosely bonded to the atom) in a conductor.